# Why does a broad-leaved evergreen (Mahonia aquifolium) has red leaves?

Tags: evolution, biochemistry, molecular-biology, botany, plant-physiology

To my knowledge, oregon grape (*[Mahonia aquifolium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahonia_aquifolium)*) is purportedly an evergreen shrub? Deciduous broadleaf plants lose their leaves in autumn usually and before that as the leaves die they oxidize and turn shades of yellow and red as carotenoids and anthocyanins are expressed.

For what reason does *M. aquifolium* turns red in the fall given that they DON'T drop their leaves? Does it somehow benefit the plant? Is it because oregon grape's ancestor used to drop leaves?

Comment: I don't know about *Mahonia aquifolium*, however, an "evergreen" plant does not mean the leaves will  stay green forever. Normally, all leaves of all kinds of plants, get old ("senescent"), take retirement from metabolic functions, store only waste products; and new leaves take the major metabolic functions. Now; a **Typical Deciduous plant** sheds all the senescent leaves on a *Particular Season of the Year*, whereas, a **so-called "Evergreen" plant, typically**, does not shade all the leaves at a particular season. Rather, they shade some leaves throughout year without bias to a season.

Comment: btw, write questions in more clear way. focus the topic you are asking about. You could also use separate paragraph or points. Also, avoid using short-scientific name from the beginning. Because, Separate, unrelated species, starting with same letter for genus, and with same "specific epithet" (of course they belong to different "species", but the "specific epithet" is same); may exist. You can use the short-name only-after you've once mentioned the full name. You need-NOT to memorize this as a rule, rather, can do it from common sense.

Comment: Tag edit suggest:  appropriate tags are botany, plant-physiology, ECOLOGY, and biochemistry. Molecular biology is not primarily  an appropriate tag (for me at least), because molecular biology is focused on the biochemistry of gene-expression mechanism. Adaptation-advantages, though discussed both in EVOLUTION and ECOLOGY, the present-day ECOLOGY seems more appropriate here, for limited number of tag-fields.

Comment: The photo input continues while the enzymatic reactions decline with failing temperatures which would mean the thylacoid pH will get out of hand. Anthocyanin shading the light harvesting centers is one means to prevent this. Yellow xanthophylls (yellow) is another but accomplishes the same end differently. It's about reducing PS2 activity, IMHO.

Comment: @user17343 I edited your post to try to improve the format. Feel free to roll back if you don't like the edit. +1 btw

Comment: Thanks to all the helpful answers!! I'm a little put off by the condescension on here, particularly in the scientific topics. It's an app, not a journal. We're coming to YOU for YOUR expertise, so talking down to people about their grammar or use of Latin here seems exceeding condescending and priggish.  Either way I appreciate all the input and time spent

Comment: Not directed at you @Remi.b

Comment: @JaguarDomingo I just had suggested you that how you could write the question so that more people could easily realize its content. I did not shown any condescension (& I'm not a  moderator).

Comment: @JaguarDomingo It is sometimes hard not to be considered pedantic when you are trying to (1) explain things and (2) improve the quality of posts so that it gets more view and motivate people to answer the question. As you agreed, we all appreciated AlwaysConfused's contribution to this post.

Comment: So, this 'condescension' label is directed at me?

Comment: No @JimYoung, I meant Always Confused --they've dogged other posts of mine with useless grammar suggestions and no actual answers or ideas. Yours was the most useful comment offered.